# Do clothes count towards encumbrance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, encumbrance

Does a character’s first set of clothes count towards encumbrance (carried weight)? I know they specifically don’t in 3.5, but I can’t find something similar in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd Q of the Equipment section of [the unofficial FAQ at d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/pathfinder-faq/#Equipment)  quotes Jason Bulmahn (Paizo's Director of Game Design) from a forum post he posted on 10/8/09:

> A: (**Jason Bulmahn 10/8/09**) Folks, **as of right now, there is nothing in
>   the RAW that states that one suit of clothing does not count toward
>   encumbrance.** So, as of this moment, clothing does count. I will
>   revisit this issue when it comes time for the next batch of updates.

(Emphasis mine.)

The core PF Erratas published since then don't seem to have addressed this question.

**I'm not 100% sure it hasn't been fixed / updated elsewhere, though.**

(Note also, please, that the same FAQ entry also quotes James Jacobs (Paizo's Creative Director) saying

> A: (James Jacobs) In games I run, one suit of worn clothing won’t
>   count for encumbrance. I’m relatively sure that the omission of that
>   line from the rules was an oversight, but it’s not something that I
>   think warrants a full-blown errata.

Nonetheless, what I've found on the Paizo forums seem to go with Jason Bulmahn's stricter reading of the RAW.)